# How to find the largest image using Java?

Tags: java, image

I am trying to parse a html page to find the most prominent image. So, after parsing the html page to extract all img tags, i am trying to find the largest image by comparing the dimension of the image.

Is it right to compare the images by calculating the area as (width * height)?

Comment: I think you need to define what you mean by "largest".

Comment: If you want to do this, by dimension (not file size), then yes, you want to use the `height * width` method.

Comment: at which time you will have answeredyour own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends entirely on your definition of 'largest'. `width * height` is certainly a valid approach, but it has the flaw that a 1x1000 image is 'larger' than a 30x30 one even though the latter could very well be more noticeable. It also has the problem that a large image that's mostly the same as the background color will be more 'noticeable' than a medium image that isn't, which might not be the case.

In order to figure out how to determine how to find the 'largest' image, you need to specify why you want it.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to fetch the correct image for a news from the source url in the rss feed item, if the image is not included in the feed item. I could not find any library in the internet to parse the html page to get the prominent image and so i am trying to write a parser myself.

Comment: In that case, largest by area seems like a good first approximation. You might want to ignore images that are smaller than a certain size for posts like http://www.cnn.com/2012/04/25/justice/connecticut-death-penalty-law-repealed/index.html?hpt=hp_t1 that don't have associated images.